# What is Post-Relational data model?

Tags: database-design

I searched in google for "what is Post-Relational data model", but I couldn't find an exact answer.
so, what is Post-Relational data model in databases and what are Post-Relational databases?
thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I can see, it's marketing BS!

Comment: Everyone tries to ignore/disregard the relational model for perceived shortcomings that are **not** part of the relational model and end up reinventing something the relational model was created to address... until they start adding in features to make it more relational (at their customers' behest) because their customers actually need a relational database, not some pre/post/quasi/anti relational "database".  But it seems like anyone these days can put an abstraction layer over a text file, call it something that sounds like a cartoon character and get at least 2 rounds of funding.

Comment: @bbaird would you please name some post relational database?

Comment: There is no such thing.  Relational is the most practical framework of data and data processing, any attempts to avoid it end up back at the same place.